# Joint Conditional PMF: is this calculation correct?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I am currently working on a review problem which I find a little confusing. The problem goes as follows:
Consider two i.i.d random variables $X$ and $Y$ with values in $\mathbb{N}_0$ such that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}_0$:
$$\mathbb{P}(X = k | X+Y=n)=\binom{n}{k}2^{-n}$$
What are the possible cummulative distributions for $X$?

My attempt at the first step is to take apart the conditional probability and setting $Z = X+Y$:

\begin{align} \mathbb{P}(X = k | Z=n) &= \frac{\mathbb{P}_{XZ}(k,n) }{\mathbb{P}_Z(n)} \\
&= \frac{\mathbb{P}_{X}(k) \mathbb{P}_{Z}(n) }{\mathbb{P}_Z(n)} \\
&= \mathbb{P}_{X}(k)
 \end{align}
I am not sure if this step is correct, because the conditional probaility is over the sum of two random variables. So my question: is what I have done correct, and if not what would be the correct approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given conditional density is a binomial $B\Big(n;\frac{1}{2}\Big)$

To show that the two marginals are  poisson's law: $X\sim Po(\theta)$  for any $\theta>0$ is not difficult...can you procede by yourself or  you need further help?

---

Assume that

- $X\sim Po(\theta)$
- $Y\sim Po(\theta)$
- $X\perp\!\!\!\!\!\! \perp Y$

It is evident that $(X+Y)\sim Po(2\theta)$

$$\mathbb{P}(X=k|X+Y=n)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(X=k)\cdot \mathbb{P}(Y=n-k)}{\mathbb{P}(X+Y=n)}=\frac{\frac{e^{-\theta}\theta^k}{k!}\cdot \frac{e^{-\theta}\theta^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}}{\frac{e^{-2\theta}(2\theta)^n}{n!}}$$

$$\mathbb{P}(X=k|X+Y=n)=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}2^{-n}=\binom{n}{k}2^{-n}$$

...as stated

That's all

---

Comment: I'd maybe need another hint. Could you perhaps tell me if the approach I have presented would lead to your result?

Comment: @ABCCHEM : Added full solution in my edited answer. It it has been useful, you can mark my answer as accepted. Thanks

Comment: Thank your for your answer! It seems to me you found the solution by inspection and then showed it was true. However, is there a way to explicitly derive the result without knowing, or recognizing, from the start what the distribution of $X$ or $Y$ has to be?

Comment: @ABCCHEM : knowing that a conditional distribution is binomial, the marginal are poisson. It's a well known relation...I do not know if there is a direct method

Comment: Okay, thank you very much! This helped a great deal :)